# Bit flags in status. Find status where one flag = 0

Tags: php, mysql, bit-manipulation

Say i have three bit flags in a status, stored in mysql as an integer

```
Approved    Has Result    Finished
0|1         0|1           0|1
```

Now i want to find the rows with status: Finished = 1, Has Result = 1 and Approved = 0.

Then the data:

```
0 "000"
1 "001"
3 "011"
7 "111"
```

Should produce

```
false
false
true
false
```

Can I do something like? (in mysql)

```
status & "011" AND ~((bool) status & "100")
```

**Can't quite figure out how to query "Approved = 0".**

Or should i completely drop using bit flags, and split these into separate columns?

The reasoning for using bit flags is, in part, for mysql performance.

Comment: Have you read documentation ?

Comment: You really should just store those in different columns so you can do proper queries.

Comment: You have 3 space-delimited statuses each with 3 binary flags held in one field? I agree with @Jessica; nuke that horror and rewrite using sane RDBMS practices.

Comment: Documentation, for what exactly? I have read up on the bitwise operators, yes. I might have to store in different columns, yes. To clarify: The storage type is integer, the spaces are just for readability.

Comment: @Digital Chris, would you create a table holding the status flags?

Comment: Can you share the output off `SHOW CREATE TABLE [table_name]`

Comment: Create a table or redesign the existing table; mysql has a BIT type. I'm not even really sure what statuses 4-9 are right now...

Comment: @DigitalChris I've reformulated the question, skipping the multiple statuses thing for now, in hope to get some clarification on the first question. So would you create separate columns for each of these boolean values?

Comment: Yes, the space cost is tiny and usability increase is huge. It makes for readable and maintainable code, easy reporting, etc.

Comment: So what's wrong with `WHERE status = 3`?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, sure. Guess i just wanted the "not approved" thing, for combined statuses in one field (i edited the question) but that does not sound like a good idea. But thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ints instead of binary text. Instead of `011`, use `3`.

To get approved rows:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `foo`
WHERE
    (`status` & 4)
```

or approved and finished rows:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `foo`
WHERE
    (`status` & 5)
```

or finished but not accepted:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `foo`
WHERE
    (`status` & 1)
AND
    (`status` ^ 4)
```

"*Finished = 1, Has Result = 1 and Approved = 0*" could be as simple as `status` = 3.

Comment: Edited the question, stating that I actually use integers. But say i want rows that are NOT approved, but finished.

Comment: @jborch You should be able to use the bitwise XOR (`^`) to do this. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Something I liked to do when I began programming was using powers of 2 as flags given a lack of boolean or bit types:

```
const FINISHED = 1;
const HAS_RESULT = 2;
const APPROVED = 4;
```

Then you can check like this:

```
$status = 5; // 101
if ($status & FINISHED) { 
    /*...*/ 
}
```

**EDIT**:

Let me expand on this:

> **Can't quite figure out how to query "Approved = 0".**
>
> Or should i completely drop using bit flags, and split these into separate columns?
>
> The reasoning for using bit flags is, in part, for mysql performance.

The issue is, you are not using bitwise flags. You are using a string which "emulates" a bitwise flag and sort of makes it hard to actually do proper flag checking. You'd have to convert it to its bitwise representation and then do the checking.

Store the flag value as an integer and declare the flag identifiers that you will then use to do the checking. A TINYINT should give you 7 possible flags (minus the most significant bit used for sign) and an unsigned TINYINT 8 possible flags.